# Using LinkButton to validate Validation Group

Tags: asp.net, webforms, validationgroup

In a .Net WebForm I have a Button working fine to validate a ValidationGroup using the following:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Validate" ValidationGroup="ClientConditions" CausesValidation="true"/>
```

However if I use a LinkButton in the same way the validate does not work:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="AgainValidate" ValidationGroup="ClientConditions" CausesValidation="true">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you hover over the link button, what does the request at the bottom left of the browser window say?

Comment: javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("LinkButton1", "",true,"ClientConditions","",false,true))

Comment: Hmmm, that looks right.

Comment: Are they side by side in code or is one maybe in an update panel?

Comment: They are both within a JQuery UI tab, side-by-side. There are no update panels.

Comment: Can you please share your validators? Also validation which you used.